# Whats a cylinder of revolution in geometry?

Tags: geometry

It would be nice if you have a link or picture of it. I have searched on the internet but I'm confused with the definitions I have found. I have seen this in examples for isoparametric surfaces in $R^3.$

Comment: Where you see this phrase? please write your reference.

Comment: @Az264 In view of what followed after your post, I retained simple geometry tag. However, if you feel your tagging is otherwise correct, please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

If parametrization is in polar coordinates $ (r,\theta, z ) $ ,then, if you fix the 3 parameters one by one (making them iso- of that parameter), then

$r= constant $ are cylinder circular cuts.
$ \theta = constant $ are radial plane cuts.
$ z = constant $ are axial plane cuts.

By "cut" I mean surface formed by holding the one  such parameter the same value and dividing volume in two parts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you refer to isoparametric surfaces, I'm going to conclude that you're talking about *tubes* around general space curves. Indeed, if you have a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ with no umbilic points and one constant principal curvature $k_1\ne 0$, then you can prove without too much difficulty that the surface is (a portion of) a tube of radius $1/|k_1|$ around a smooth curve. (If $k_1=0$, then you get — at least locally — a general developable ruled surface, which can be either a cone, a cylinder, or a tangent developable.)

Comment: "Tubes around general curves" wouldn't be "of revolution" as said in the title of the OP.

Comment: Since I've never heard the term in my 40+ years as a differential geometer, @JeanMarie, I'm still waiting for a definition. The OP mentioned isoparametric surfaces as an example. .

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_revolution)

Comment: Kindly don't insult my intelligence, @JeanMarie.

Comment: I never had this intention.

Comment: I have the same view as @JeanMarie. No disrespect here.

Comment: If all we're talking about is right circular cylinders, then this is no differential geometry question and the terminology is arcane,

Comment: Yes, so edited it.